# CSS to create a outline transition from right to left?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have one search field. When click on on that field (focused), it should provide solid blue colored outline and while forming this outline, it should transition from right to left as provided in the image.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a solution that uses a little more HTML...

```css
.text-input {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

.parent-border{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.border {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.border:focus-within{
  width: 0%;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-border">
  <div class="border">
    <input class="text-input"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```